# Finding all possible routes Java

Tags: java, routes

I am doing a project which i have to load a list of flights details from a text file. I read the text file and have load the 3 values into a hashmap. The 3 values are in this format (Airport ID, To, From). The To and From are being put into a list before putting into hashmap together with the ID.

I am **having trouble with finding all possible routes from a selected To and From**. I have read up on Dijkstra's algorithm but i did not know how to apply this due to lack of knowledge.

Below is an example of my code which i am able to find the direct flight and flight with 1 transfer point.

```
for (int i = 0; i < route.get("all").size(); i++) {
        String boardAir = route.get("all").get(i).from;
        String alightAir = route.get("all").get(i).to;
        if (boardAir.equals(ar.boardAirport) && alightAir.equals(ar.alightAirport)) {
            airline = route.get("all").get(i).id;
            System.out.println("Direct Airlines = " + alr.airline1.get(airline));
            System.out.println("From = " + ar.airport1.get(boardAir) + "\tDestination = " + ar.airport1.get(alightAir));
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            System.out.println("No direct flight found.");
        }
        if (boardAir.equals(ar.boardAirport)) {
            for (int j = 0; j < route.get(route.get("all").get(i).id).size(); j++) {
                String transfer = route.get(route.get("all").get(i).id).get(j).from;
                String finalDest = route.get(route.get("all").get(i).id).get(j).to;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove the commented code, it will be better to read and understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dijkstra's algorithm would be a good algorithm to study. If you read up on it, and are still having trouble, there are some additional resources I would suggest. First, there is a pretty good Algorithms book from Princeton University that is completely online. You can find that at http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/ and the chapter you should reference is Chapter 4. It comes complete with sample code and I think it will provide enough information for you. Otherwise, check out a YouTube search for "Dijkstra's Algorithm" if you are more of a visual learner. There are actually some good vids up there.